# Going through a handler class object to read console

Tags: java

you may have seen my previous question, this builds on that with the implementation of a handler. however im finding it difficult to get it to work correctly.

i have three classes:

main.java
- simple method which requests to read console and then outputs the user input.

handler.java
- requests 'readconsole' from gui.java

gui.java 
- displays gui
- reads console

feel like im missing something simple!

main.java

```java
public class main {

    static handler handler = new handler();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public static void menuSwitch(String input)  {

        System.out.println("entered menu switch with input " +input);
        String s = handler.requestReadConsole();
        System.out.println(s);

}
}
```

handler.java

```java
public class handler {

    static gui gui = new gui();

    static String inputvariable= null;

    public handler() {
        requestAndSortReadConsole();
    }


    public String requestReadConsole() {
        System.out.println("entered read console");
        String s = gui.readConsole();
        return s;
    }


    public String requestAndSortReadConsole() {
        System.out.println("entered requestAndSortReadConsole");
        sortInput(requestReadConsole());

        System.out.println("sorted value = " + inputvariable);
        return inputvariable;
    }



    public void sortInput(String input) {
        System.out.println("entered sort input with input = " + input);

        if (input.length() == 1) {  
            System.out.println("input length EQUALS 1");
            main.menuSwitch(input);         
        }else {

            inputvariable = input;
            System.out.println(inputvariable);
        }
        System.out.println("return input");
    }
    }
```

gui.java

```java
public class gui {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public gui() {
        System.out.println("main menu called");
        mainMenu();

    }

    public void mainMenu() {
        System.out.println("press 1 for case 1");
        System.out.println("press 2 for case 2");
        System.out.println("press 3 for case 3");
    }

    public String readConsole () {
        String input = null;
        System.out.println("entered readconsole gui");
        input = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("input  = " + input);
        in.close();
        return input;
    }






}
```

The method `menuSwitch` should print variable `s` but it doesnt print anything and continues to allow user to input to console!

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: class names start with a capital letter. I'm surprised the compiler doesn't object to a non-constructor `main()` method in a class named `main`.

Comment: sorry, this was only quick type out of code for Stackoverflow, as i didnt want to paste my full class.